# json argument passed from the command line with python can't be decoded

Tags: python, json, command

I am trying to pass a command line argument to a python file and load the json but
I keep getting a valueerror: No Json object could be decoded.

json_test.py:

```
import json
import sys

json_dict = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

I then run this in the command line using:

```
python json_test.py '{"favorited": false, "contributors": null}'
```

And I get an error, even though I found this as an example of correct JSON on the web.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message? It is working for me.

Comment: use simplejson for better error messages

Comment: @H20   
File "json_test.py", line 4, in <module>
json_dict = json.laods(sys.argv[1])
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, inx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @andi can't use simplejson for the computer I'm working on, it's offline

Comment: What OS are you using? What shell? What appears on stdout when you `print (sys.argv[1])`?

Comment: @Robᵩ  I'm using Windows 10 (with Windows command line) and Python 2.7.6 (not my choice)

Comment: Can you confirm that `sys.argv[1]` has what you think it has? Perhaps by `print repr(sys.argv[1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run `print sys.argv[1]` you probably get `'{favorited:` which the json module cannot decode into a json object.

try escaping your inner quotes so it is passed as 1 argument like so:

```
"{"\""favorited"\"": false, "\""contributors"\"": null}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick.  Do you know if this is a Windows issue, or have any sources that explain how/when I need to do this while passing json?

Comment: if you read json from a file you don't have to do this (note you would probably use load instead of laods), however windows terminal seems like you have to @DavidJ.

Comment: if you're on a windows platform, use addslashes() to add slashes in the string.